# Agregarle estilos al enviar un correo electronico en ASP.NET

Tags: c#, .net, asp, visual, studio

necesito un poco de ayuda, tengo un formulario que pide nombre, correo electronico, asunto y mensaje, al dar click en enviar manda un correo a la direccion proporcionada por el mismo usuario. Lo que quiero implementar es como agregarle estilos o colores al correo que se le envia al usuario, tipo como la imagen que adjunto

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Me gustaria dijeran como implementar eso en .NET ASP

Comment: Es bastante sencillo, el cuerpo del correo debe ser un html con su correspondiente css. Te dejo una guía http://csharp.net-informations.com/communications/csharp-html-email.htm

Comment: Usa lo que recomienda Lobos, agrega tu codigo por si tienes un problema en la visualizacion del html.